# I would like a way to have a "try again" for wrong user inputs. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

So I've got a list of files I'm looping over and a list of folders, I match my filenames to the folders  that contain matching words and that works fine. My code will detect if there's a matching_folder for a file and tell me which one/s, then I can type the name of that folder and it will move it to that folder. It loops over files in the list, and it can be a large list sometimes. However, if I accidentally type the name of the folder wrong, which is a user input, it passes my file and moves on to the next one. Is there a way I can get my code to NOT move onto the next file. but instead prompt me again?

```
    if len(matching_folders) >= 2:
       print(f"There is MORE than one folder for {filename}" + "\n")
       if not filename in files_to_move:
          continue
       for item in matching_folders:
          print(item + "\n")
       answer_2 = input(f"Type name of folder: " + "\n")
       item_words = answer_2.lower().split(' ')
       for folder in folder_list: 
          count = 0
          folder_words = folder.lower().split(' ')
          for word in item_words:
             if word in folder_words:
                count += 1
          if count == 2:
             folder_path = os.path.join(paths[1], folder)
             destination_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
             shutil.move(source_file_path, destination_file_path)
             print(f"File moved to --> {folder}")
```

Excuse me if this is bad code but I'm just learning. I am taking it one step at time. But again, if I make a typo, my code goes onto the next file in the loop (there's actually a for loop for filename one level above all my code, but there's a lot of other irrelevant stuff above it so I didn't include it). I want it to not go to the next file if I make a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.isdir(user_inputted_folder)` to control your logic. This will return True if the `user_inputted_folder` exists and is a directory (not a regular file).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir

If the actual folder is named "Folder1", and you misinput "Folderrr1", then this will return False as long as "Folderrr1" doesn't also exist (if it exists, then this "typo" can't be caught).

Comment: Where would I place that? Would I also need a while loop to loop while True?

Comment: A while loop that checks an `invalid_folder_flag` (a flag is a variable that you set to True or False) works. Set the flag to True right before the loop. Set it to False (within the loop) once the user provides a valid `user_inputted_folder`. The loop can be placed anywhere before the `user_inputted_folder` gets used, and just keeps looping until it gets a "valid" input. I would put it in the same place you initially ask for the `user_inputted_folder` for the sake of being concise.